# populating text fields from the sql using dropdown list Jquery

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hello there first time doing this, Basically I am rather confused on how to Re-populate text boxes from the database.

My current issue is that basically I have two tables in my database 'USER' and 'STATISTICS'.
Currently what is working is that my code is looking up the values of 'User_ID' in the 'USER' table and populating the values in the drop down list.

What I want from there is for the text fields to populate corresponding to those values from the database looking up the 'User_ID' E.G 'goal_scored' , 'assist', 'clean_sheets' and etc.

I am pretty baffled I have looked up on various different questions but cannot find what im looking for.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("f_club",$link);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user ";
$aResult = mysql_query($sql);

?>

<html>
<body>
<title>forms</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<form action="update.php" method="post">
<h1>Enter User Details</h1>
<h2>
<p> <label for="User_ID"> User ID: </label> <select id="User_ID" id="User_ID" name="User_ID" >
   <br> <option value="">Select</option></br>
    <?php
        $sid1 = $_REQUEST['User_ID'];

        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($aResult,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {

        $User_ID = $rows['User_ID'];
        if($sid1 == $id)
        {
        $chkselect = 'selected';

        }
        else
        {
        $chkselect ='';
        }
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo  $id;?>"<?php echo $chkselect;?>>
        <?php echo $User_ID;?></option>
        <?php }
        ?>
        I had to put this in because everytime I have text field under the User_ID it goes next to it and cuts it off :S


         <p><label for="null"> null: </label><input type="text" name="null" /></p>
    <p><label for="goal_scored">Goal Scored: </label><input type="text" name="Goal_Scored" /></p>
    <p><label for="assist">assist: </label><input type="text" name="assist"  /></p>
    <p><label for="clean_sheets">clean sheets: </label><input type="text" name="clean_sheets" /></p>
    <p><label for="yellow_card">yellow card: </label><input type="text" name="yellow_card" /></p>
    <p><label for="red_card">red card: </label><input type="text" name="red_card" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" /></p></h2>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can help with understanding how to get to the next stage would be much appreciated thanks x

Comment: Well...you need to tell the server which user has been selected. Either do an AJAX request and retrieve the data to directly put it into the text fields or just send the form to the server and have the PHP script retrieve the corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than spending time on something complicated like AJAX, I'd recommend going the simple route of pages with queries, such as `user.php?id=1`.

Craft a `user.php` file (like yours) and if `id` is set (`if isset($_GET['id'])`) select that user from the database (after having sanitised your input, of course) with `select * from users where id = $id` (I of course assume you have an `id` for each user).

You can still have the `<select>`, but remember to close it with `</select>`.  You might end up with something like this:

```
<form method="get">
  <label for="user">Select user:</label>
  <select name="id" id="user">
    <option value="1">User 1</option>
    ...
  </select>
  <submit name="submit" value="Select user" />
</form>
```

This will send `?id=<id>` to the current page and you can then fill in your form.  If you further want to edit that data, create a new form with the data filled in with code like `<input type="text" name="goal_scored" value="<?php echo $result['goal_scored']; ?>" />` then make sure the `method="post"` and listen on `isset($_POST['submit'])` and update your database.

An example:

```
<?php
// init
// Use mysqli_ instead, mysql_ is deprecated
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, name FROM users");
// Create our select
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($link, $result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {?>
  <option value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><?php echo $result['name'] ?></option>
<?php}

// More code ommitted

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = sanitise($_GET['id']); // I recommend creating a function for this,
                               // but if only you are going to use it, maybe
                               // don't bother.
  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id");
  // now create our form.

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // data to be updated
    $data = sanitise($_POST['data']);
    // ...

    mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET data = $data, ... WHERE id = $id");
    // To avoid the 'refresh to send data thing', you might want to do a
    // location header trick
    header('Location: user.php?id='.$id);
  }
}
```

Remember, this is just an example of the idea I'm talking about, lots of code have been omitted.  I don't usually like writing actually HTML outside `<?php ?>` tags, but it can work, I guess.  Especially for smaller things.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will let you know how I get on implementing it.

Comment: its not what im looking for... I actually refined a bit of the code, rather than looking into the user table I changed it to the statistics table. I still want too know how I can go about doing this. I have looked into AJAX onchange, but still I cannot figure it out. Any help?